# Remove silence in a wav file in android

Tags: android, audio, wav, audiorecord

I'm writing an application where a wav file is recorded.The gaps (silence) in the wav file is removed by a threshold. Since this often causes a runthrough between the last note and the next note. How can I add a constant silence in between whenever the speaker gives a long pause.

```
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, 
        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding); 

        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, 
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize); 

        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        while (started) {
            int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != bufferReadResult){
                  //check signal
                //put a threshold
                  int foundPeak=searchThreshold(buffer,threshold);
                    if (foundPeak>-1){ //found signal
                                            //record signal

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        byte[] byteBuffer =ShortToByte(buffer,bufferReadResult);

                    try {
                            os.write(byteBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }else{//count the time
                        //don't save signal
                    }
```